# How to use a string variable as src link in embed tag?

Tags: html, typescript, src

I have to implement a document viewer in my project.
Due to limitation, the link for the document is received as a router parameter and received properly in a variable named `link` in doclauncher.ts file
now I tried this two options in `doclauncher.html` file but none of them seem to work:

```
div class="container">
  <embed id = "doc"
    src = ""
    type="application/pdf"
    height="100%"
    width="100%"
  />
</div>
<script>
  document.getElementById("doc").src= '+ {{link}} +'
</script>
```

and

```
div class="container">
  <embed id = "doc"
    src = {{link}}
    type="application/pdf"
    height="100%"
    width="100%"
  />
</div>
```

What should I do?
Using Angular 11.2.13 and backend in typescript
edit: This is how link was retrieved

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
      this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.link = params['link'];
    });
}
```

I have checked by printing the this.link that it is ok :)

Comment: {{ }} brackets are framework dependant. so need to check whether  framework or base technology is providing value when called through {{ }} syntax. try console.log it. Normally  document.getElementById("doc").src= '+ link +'; should have sufficed as far as JS alone was concerned.

Comment: I am using Angular 11.2.13 and typescript... this too did not work

Comment: then just run through console.log and see if any error error props up....if the above code it self is not working then error would mount for that or if code is working but for what ever reasons link value is slightly behind   or link is scoped somewhere else or has value not as expected console would state that. hit refresh to with developers tools turned on. I taking an running guess that {{ }} have its own computational cost where as src attribute has its own thread which is way way faster and executes on DOM content ready state ahead of everything else and starts fetching things.

Comment: try this take the actually value that would have replaced with {{link}}. add it as string e.g. src = '/path/file.pdf' run to see if code works. if it does then we have thread race. Browser Object Model executed src way before framework could replace value.

Comment: just adding into above thats how we do lazy loading..... we either keep src value empty and then through trigger aka when user goes pass certain  view range we replace empty value with actual value. Moment that value is changes browser kick starts fetch process in less then a blink of an eye. That is BOM behaviour you cannot change it.

Comment: Thus if above is the case theoretically speaking, then keep src value empty string src='', then though function replace the value. Simple templeting wont work because it happens when DOM ready state is complete. Browser has done a lot by then ...I would make an example of theoretic and please  down vote its an example of hint.

Comment: just as answer shlock has provided below ...the gist is here in this example https://js.do/code/601999

Comment: @syed Thanks for all your comments.
1. Giving src a custom path works fine.
2. But I have tried with the same link through variable but it didn't work even if the address bar of the web app at that instant shown exactly the same string inboth of the cases
3. recently I tried replacing as u suggested and as answered by Shlok but it still the same... i don't know where is the fault...
....And thanks again for so much help :)

Comment: I am also adding the code snippet that used to retrieved ...can it be that link variable is not of proper type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233380/discussion-between-suman-and-syed).

Answer (score 1):

Use setattribute like this

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("doc")setAttribute("src", "{{link}}")
</script>
```